# Why does C# warn about unused event in generic class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

With this code:

```
public class Peyton
{
    public event Action Wobble;

    protected void OnWobble()
    {
        Wobble();
    }
}
```

I get no warning. But if I make the class generic:

```
public class Peyton<T>
{
    public event Action Wobble;

    protected void OnWobble()
    {
        Wobble();
    }
}
```

I get a warning that "the event `Killian.Gameplay.Peyton.Wobble' is never used."

Why am I getting this warning?

NOTE: this is with Unity 5.3's version of Mono, i.e. Mono 2.6.5

Comment: So which version of the Mono compiler is this? It may well be a bug that was fixed long ago.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- hi John, first thanks for all your C# (and F#) writing -- have learnt a lot from you. It's mono 2.6.5.

Comment: But is that the *compiler* version (`mcs`)? It looks like Mono 2.6.5 itself was released some time mid-2010, so I wouldn't be surprised if there were bug fixes in the last 5 1/2 years...

Comment: Unity is bundled with something called gmcs that with the `--version` flag prints the following: "Mono C# compiler version 2.6.5.0" Not very helpful... Yeah, Unity being (very) behind the latest mono is a constant source of pain. Anyhow, good to know I'm not losing my mind and that this warning doesn't seem right.

Comment: Right, so it really is that version for the compiler too. Sorry - I think you'll just have to ignore it. (You could do so with a `#pragma`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet -- yeah that's what I've done, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mono-compiler-and-library-version-with-unity-installation.38944/#post-249643), Unity provides its own customized framework, even if there is a system installed Mono.  Even if it's using an up-to-date compiler, it has overrides to a lot of C# functionality, up to and including the [equality operator](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/), due to the way the engine works.  It may be the Unity Mono causing your issue.